# Given a manifold sub-atlas is the differentiable structure unique?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

If we are given a subatlas $\{ (U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)\}_\alpha$ of a manifold $\mathcal M$, is the differentiable structure unique (i.e.  is its maximal extension unique)?

Comment: the question is not very clear (and is not currently grammatically correct). is your sub-atlas taken so that transition functions are smooth?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki Yes, I define a sub-atlas as a set of tuples of open sets and coordinate functions such that transition functions are smooth. My definition of manifold is a set M with a differentiables structure and a differentiable structure is a maximal smooth sub-atlas.

Comment: Suppose we are given a particular sub-atlas (maybe it has two charts) can we add additional charts in a unique way? My guess is yes, but I'm not sure. Sorry for the grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Given any sub-atlas $S$, you may obtain a maximal atlas $A$ containing it by adjoining all compatible charts. Now suppose $A'$ is another maximal atlas containing $S$. Then in particular all the charts in $A'$ are compatible with $S$, so by construction of $A$ we must have $A' \subset A$. Since we assumed both to be maximal, we conclude that $A' = A$.